# Поиск файла в директории

Tags: python

Каким образом, в пайтоне, я могу найти файлы с типом .txt и при этом название которых начинается, например, на "result".
То есть в моей папке файлы: `result_275.txt`, `result_351.txt`, `task.txt`

Как программе найти эти файлы и, например, вывести их названия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, при помощи функции [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('result_*.txt')
```